# Memory of an episode no one remembers from Star Trek?

Tags: identify-this-episode, star-trek

I have distinct memory of a Star Trek episode no one remembers! It is about Spock and Kirk going down to a dying planet with ruins around a dying star that comes to life as a person on the planet (Celia Lovsky). She is angry her children are being attacked and have run under the surface. She rocks the planet and has anger bouts till she understands her children went underground 11,000 years ago, and died off... She then lets the Captain and Mister Spock go after realizing she sees time differently than her children that had died in her transformation.

Never seen it again, and never heard of anyone having it ever again. It was in the mid 1960's when I saw it on TV and I live in Quebec Canada if that helps. Her face, the dialogue, the set... I remember all of it but no one else does! Was it lost? Destroyed? Rejected and exist somewhere in some safe? I have no clue why I remember a whole episode no one else does.

Comment: I'll eat my phaser if this is an actual episode.

Comment: Celia Lovsky played T'Pau, so the episode was amok time that she was in. Which has no resemblance at all to the described episode, which was not one of the original ST episodes.

Comment: Is it possible you're confusing her appearance as T'Pau on Star Trek with the plot of some other sci-fi show/movie she appeared in?

Comment: I can't believe two people understood this post.

Comment: You may find [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series) helpful. It's has all the episode listed, and it may help jog your memory until someone can provide you with an answer.

Comment: FWIW, Star Trek: The Animated Series had some bizarre story lines, and one or more of its episodes may contain elements in your outline, but I doubt any of its stories would fit the outline you gave.

Answer (score 14):

### This is not a *Star Trek: TOS* episode

..**at least not a SINGLE episode**.

It has elements of several TOS episodes that you may be amalgamating or conflating. The elements / episodes in question...

- *The Devil in the Dark*

...has a creature (not human) defending her children against mining of a planet

> The Horta species possessed (as compared to carbon-based lifeforms) an unusually long life span. Every fifty thousand years, all of the Horta died out except for one, the so-called mother Horta, who then watched the eggs until they hatched, and mothered and protected them.

---

- *Amok Time*

The **only** TOS episode in which Celia Lovsky appears

---

- *For the World is Hollow and I Have Touched the Sky*

This has many elements which match your memory...

The *Enterprise* encounters a space-ship/asteroid which houses the remains of the Fabrini,  a civilization wiped out **10,000 years ago, when their star went nova.**

> Towards the end, the Fabrini were living underground. Some of them, who later became known as the Creators, built the asteroid spaceship Yonada, crewed the ship with the choicest candidates, and sent the ship into space. For the people who stayed behind on the planet, they were destroyed by the sun's nova.
>
> <sup>[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fabrini)</sup>

On the asteroid/ship the guiding computer fights them, **kicking up a storm** and increasing the temperature in the room to 120 degrees planning to burn them to death or until they die of heat stroke.

Comment: The OP's outline also calls to my mind elements of "The City on the Edge of Forever" and "The Empath"